# VBA function returns a value although return value is not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I found this function which VBA IDE compiles fine when I click on the *"Debug / Compile VBAProject"*:

```
Public Function getArrayLength(ByRef myArray)
    If (IsEmpty(myArray)) Then
        getArrayLength = 0
    Else
        getArrayLength = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray) + 1
    End If
End Function
```

It has no *"return type"* defined and no *"parameter type"* defined.

I already found from the official reference ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#variant-data-type)) that `myArray` is assigned type `Variant` if we don't explicitly assign any type to it.

But what happens with the *"return type"*? In this case project compiles so something is returned. But what?

Comment: If the return type is not declared then the default is `Variant`.

Comment: @RaymondWu So in this case `UBound` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function)) and `Lbound` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa445057(v=vs.60))) functions both return type `Long`... But we return `Variant`. Is `Long` supported by `Variant`? I didn't see it listed in the first link that I posted in my question.

Comment: `Variant` can be anything so yes, it can be `Long`. Following your code example - If you declare 2 different variables (say `Dim varResult` and `Dim lngResult As Long`) then assign the result of `getArrayLength` to both variables, you can see in the Local Window that `varResult` is of type `Variant/Long` and `lngResult` is `Long` as declared.

Comment: Since the topic is on `Function`, if you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement#:~:text=separated%20by%20commas.-,type,-Optional.%20Data%20type), and click the link for `Data Type`, you will see that it says `Variant` is the [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#:~:text=Date%2C%20String%2C%20Object%2C-,Variant,-(default)%2C%20and%20user)

Comment: I read this the first link that you posted regarding the `Functions` and i couldn't find it ewplicitly written.

Comment: Click the 2nd link, about `Data Type`. Basically if you don't explicitly declare the data type, it will be declared as `Variant`.

Comment: Everything stated above is true, but `Variant` being a completely general declaration, I would also like to know how did you declare your array in the `Sub` calling the function you show. As `Dim myArr` or `Dim myArr()`? Only the second one explicitly declares an array (of `Variant` elements type). The first one can become an array too, in some circumstances. But for the two different declarations type, the function you show, or its equivalent should be a little different for each. Otherwise, it will raise an error for the real array...